# couchdb - problems grouping collections

Tags: view, couchdb, mapreduce

I'm having problems trying to get my head around getting a collection of types along with number of times a skill is found in that doc type.

There are a number of document types that have a list of skills.

```
{
   "skills": "Windows, Network Admin, Linux",
   "type": "Experience"
},
{
   "skills": "Windows, Erlang, Linux",
   "type": "Experience"
},

{
   "skills": "Ruby, Rails, Erlang",
   "type": "Project"
}
```

I'm trying to get the number of times a skill is found in an document type.

The end result should look something like this:

```
{
  'type': Experience,
  'skills': [
    {'skill': 'Erlang', 'count': 1},
    {'skill': 'Linux', 'count': 2},
    {'skill': 'Network Admin', 'count': 1},
    {'skill': 'Rails', 'count': 0},
    {'skill': 'Ruby', 'count': 0},
    {'skill': 'Windows', 'count': 2}
  ]
},
{
  'type': Project,
  'skills': [
    {'skill': 'Erlang', 'count': 1},
    {'skill': 'Linux', 'count': 0},
    {'skill': 'Network Admin', 'count': 0},
    {'skill': 'Rails', 'count': 1},
    {'skill': 'Ruby', 'count': 1},
    {'skill': 'Windows', 'count': 0}
  ]
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are map and reduce functions (view named `skill_split`) and a list function that will produce output close to what you asked for using a URL like this `http://127.0.0.1:5984/myskills/_design/myskills/_list/transform/skill_split?group=true`:

```
{
   "Experience": {"Erlang":1, "Linux":2, "Network Admin":1, "Windows":2},
   "Project":{"Erlang":1, "Rails":1, "Ruby":1}
}
```

I can tweak the code to make the output exactly what you asked for, but the list function would be a bit longer.

**map**:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type && doc.skills) {
    doc.skills.split(', ').forEach(function(skill) {
      emit([doc.type, skill], 1);
    });
  }
}
```

**reduce**:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values)
}
```

or use `"reduce": "_sum"` for short

**list** (named `transform`):

```
function(head, req) {
  var results = {};
  var row;
  while (row = getRow()) {
    var skill_map;
    if (results.hasOwnProperty(row.key[0])) {
      skill_map = results[row.key[0]];
    } else {
      skill_map = {};
      results[row.key[0]] = skill_map;
    }

    if (skill_map.hasOwnProperty(row.key[1])) {
      skill_map[row.key[1]] = skill_map[row.key[1]] + row.value;
    } else {
      skill_map[row.key[1]] = row.value;
    }
  }
  send(JSON.stringify(results));
}
```

If you don't have access to the JSON object (you do inside a CouchApp), you might have to jump through some hoops to get access to it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the closest solution for my problem :D

Answer (score 1):

You should store the skill list in your docs as a real list.

```
{
   "skills": ["Windows", "Network Admin", Linux"],
   "type": "Experience"
}
```

From there, your map function becomes:

```
function(doc) {
  for(var skill in doc.skills) {
    emit([doc.type, skill], 1);
  }
}
```

And the reduce function just sums the result, so use "[_sum](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions#A_sum)". You can easily choose to show only Experience or Project with start and end keys.

Comment: I did have a similar solution previously but it did not solve the problem of not giving me the ability to determine there are no Ruby skills found in any experience entries. The above structure is needed so that I can render graphs.

Comment: Cygal's solution lets you determine there are no Ruby skills found in any experience entries, because when you query the view for the key `["Experience","Ruby"]` you would get no results.

Comment: True but for this particular problem I need to have the same amount of skills in each entry along with the count. The data is being passed to a graph which expects there to be the same amount of results and values in each entry. I can hack this with some jQuery but I want to use this functionality else where and rather not duplicate the data manipulation.

Comment: You need to have some way of emitting the "count: 0". The only way I can think of is to have another doc containing all possible skills and emitting {["Experience", skill],0} and {["Project", skill], 0} for each of them. It also means potentially two docs to update when adding an experience or a project.

Comment: The only other way is to save every non-skill in each doc. It takes space but gives you the ability to have "transactions": you update only one document when adding a new skill.

Comment: Cheers for the ideas Cygal, could you explain your 2nd idea a little more for me please. I was also thinking along the lines of adding a collective skills doc or field for each doc. I also probably should mention that there are a number of these entries (a user can have a number of experience, project and skill set entries). So adding a collection of skills to each doc would be over kill I think. Though creating a collective skills doc is looking more appealing.